# CXF and when should I use JaxWsProxyFactoryBean or JAX-WS Proxy

Tags: java, cxf

JaxWsProxyFactoryBean and when I should use Java stub generated from wsdl or JAX-WS Proxy?

Are there any advantages or disadvantages?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory bean is specific to CXF but non-standard. It gives you fine control over the endpoint. The other options are standard but give you less control or less convenient control.